# naming and saving workspace variables to a file with a changing number in the name - Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, save, printf, eval

So the output of my code produce many variables in every loop in Matlab workspace. I want to save two of the variables (namely MO and Vr) to a file having a fixed name with a number which change in every loop. The number which changes in each loop is "NT+1".
First I change the name of the two desired variables with following code:

```
eval(sprintf('MO%d=MO;',NT+1));
eval(sprintf('Vr%d=Vr;',NT+1));
```

Now I want to save the renamed MO and Vr variables in a .mat file having the NT+1 number at the end. For instance, if NT+1=60, I want the the two renamed variables (which are MO60 and Vr60) be saved in a file having the NT+1 number at the end: sim60.mat

```
save('sim%d.mat','MO%d','Vr%d',NT+1)
```

hypothetical, the output of the above code should be a file named 'sim60.mat' having the two variables MO60 and Vr60.

How can I automatically perform such saving when the NT+1 changes in every loop and the name of MO and Vr also must be changed for the save command at each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rename the workspace variables because you will need to use `eval`, which is almost always bad practice.

Go with

```
% create file name
flNm = num2str(i,'sim%d.mat');
% save file
save(flNm,'MO','Vr');
```

if you now load the file, load it to a struct

```
flNm = num2str(i,'sim%d.mat');
Dat = load(flNm,'MO','Vr');
% access the variables
Dat.Mo
Dat.Vr
```

usually one needs to load and save variables within a loop because the memory is too small to store them in a multidimensional array or a cell:

```
i_max = 10;
MO_all = NaN(3,3,i_max)
Vr_all = cell(i_max)
for i = 1:i_max
    % what happens in every loop
    MO = rand(3,3);
    Vr = rand(randi(10),randi(10)); % changing size
    % store for other loops
    MO_all(:,:,i) = MO;
    Vr_all{i} = Vr;
end
```

The solution to you particular question is
(**I do not recommend using this** as it is not flexible, not robust and requires `eval` to create the variables in the first place!)

```
flNm = num2str(NT+1,'sim%d.mat');
vars2save = {num2str(NT+1,'MO%d'),num2str(NT+1,'Vr%d')};
save('sim%d.mat',vars2save {:})
```